# Galois group of $x^6 + 3$ isomorphic to a copy of $S_3$ inside $S_6$

Tags: galois-theory

I have seen the the thread  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65095/galois-group-exercise-x63) related to the computation of the Galois group of the same polynomial. However, my question is not about the computation itself but about the group presentation of the Galois group. I will explain.

I have determined that the polynomial $x^6 +3 \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ has Galois group of order 6. The splitting field is $\Bbb{Q}(a)$, where $a$ is a root of $x^6 + 3$. One can take  $a = \sqrt[6]{3}\zeta$ where $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/6} = e^{\pi i/6}$.

Now I have determined the rest of the roots to be:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc} \alpha_1 &=&  a &&& \alpha_4 = -\alpha_1  \\ \alpha_2 &=& \frac{a^4 + a}{2}= \zeta a &&&  \alpha_5 = -\alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 &=& \frac{a^4 - a}{2} = \zeta^2 a &&& \alpha_6 = - \alpha_3 \end{array}. $$

I have also computed some automorphisms of the Galois group, for example the automorphism $\tau : \alpha_1 \mapsto \alpha_4$ that has order 2, $\sigma : \alpha_1 \mapsto \alpha_2$ that has order 2 and  $\rho : \alpha_1 \mapsto \alpha_3$ that has order 3. The presence of two automorphisms of order 2 tells me that the Galois group is isomorphic to $S_3$

However the problem now is if I want to identify my $\tau,\sigma$ and $\rho$ as cycles in $S_6$, I get the cycles $(14)$, $(12)$ and $(132)$. I don't think these cycles lie in the copy of $S_3$ inside of $S_6$; what am I misunderstanding here?

Thanks.

---

**Edit:** I made a mistake in the calculations. We actually need $\alpha_1 = a = \sqrt[3]{3}\zeta$ where $\zeta = e^{\pi i/6}$. I did not take a *primitive* 6-th root of unity earlier. Now if I write $a = \sqrt[6]{3}e^{\pi i/6}$, then $a^3 = \sqrt{3}i$ and so $\frac{1 + a^3}{2} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2} = \zeta^2$. So indeed with the redefined $\zeta$ and $a$, the equations now are

$$\begin{array}{ccccc} \alpha_1 &=&  a &&& \alpha_4 = -\alpha_1  \\ \alpha_2 &=& \frac{a^4 + a}{2}= \zeta^2 a &&&  \alpha_5 = -\alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 &=& \frac{a^4 - a}{2} = \zeta^4 a &&& \alpha_6 = - \alpha_3. \end{array} $$

After all this mess, I have got the automorphisms $\sigma = (12)(45)(36)$ and $\gamma = (135)(246)$. We check that $\sigma\gamma = \gamma^2\sigma$. $\sigma\gamma = (12)(36)(45)(135)(246) = (16)(25)(34)$.

$\gamma^2\sigma = (153)(264)(12)(36)(45) = (16)(25)(34)$ so indeed $\sigma\gamma = \gamma^2\sigma$. Hence the Galois group has elements

$$\{1,\gamma,\gamma^2,\sigma,\sigma\gamma, \sigma\gamma^2\} = \{1, (135)(246),(153)(264),(12)(45)(36),(14)(23)(56),(16)(34)(25)\}.$$

Comment: Hmm. With your $a$ I get $a^6=3$. But weren't we supposed to have $a^6=-3$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes I think you're right. I have a feeling that I want that $\zeta$ to actually be $e^{\pi i/6}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have edited the the post.

Comment: Remember that as the polynomial $x^6+3$ is irreducible, the Galois group will act transitively on the set of roots. Also, if an automorphism interchanges $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, surely it will also interchange $\alpha_4$ and $\alpha_5$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Where can I find out how many copies of $S_3$ sit inside of $S_6$?

Comment: There are several copies. $|S_3|=6$, so the copy given by the proof of Cayley's theorem comes to mind. Not forgetting its conjugates :-)

Comment: Take any element $x$ of order 2, and any element $y$ of order 3. If $xy=y^2x$ then you've got yourself a copy of $S_3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The problem isn't determining if it's $S_3$, the problem is determining *which copy* of $S_3$ it is inside of $S_6$. I would like to do this in order to compute fixed fields and things like that.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, complex conjugation amounts to $(16)(25)(34)$. Together with $\tau$ from Gerry's answer that should be enough, as any two involutions generate all of $S_3$.

Comment: Oi! You asked how many copies of $S_3$ sit inside of $S_6$. My comment was intended to give you a start on answering that question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh sorry, I misunderstood what you meant :D

Comment: My $\sigma$ that sends $\alpha_1$ to $\alpha_2$ should be $(12)(45)(36)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I get $\gamma : \alpha_1 \mapsto \alpha_3$ to be of order 3. I think $\alpha_1 \mapsto \alpha_3 \mapsto \alpha_5$ that maps back to $\alpha_1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Indeed with my $\gamma = (135)(246)$ and $\sigma = (12)(45)(36)$ I get that $\sigma\gamma = \gamma^2 \sigma$. Hooray!!

Comment: Sorry, Benjamin. I was typing an answer, so I missed you last comment. Feel free to write that as an answer, and I will delete mine.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Don't worry, I have accepted yours 100%! Anyway from the relations I got above, I got all the elements of my Galois group now. I was a bit confused because I realised that there is not ***one*** copy of $S_3$ inside of $S_6$!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your help.

Comment: You've got a typo in your last equation, right side, 4th element of the set.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have corrected it. Also there was a typo before on the same element that I have corrected too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Galois theory we know that there exists an automorphism $\sigma$ with the property
$$\sigma:\alpha_1\mapsto\alpha_2=\frac{\alpha^4+\alpha}2.$$
From this we can deduce that
$$
\sigma(a^3)=\left(\frac{a+a^4}2\right)^3=\frac{a^{12}+3a^9+3a^6+a^3}8.
$$
Here in the numerator $a^{12}=-3a^6$ and $a^9=-3a^3$, so this simplifies to $-a^3$ and hence
$$
\sigma(\zeta_6)=\sigma\left(\frac{1+a^3}2\right)=\frac{1-a^3}2=\zeta_6^{-1}.
$$
Therefore $\sigma(\alpha_2)=\alpha_1$, and by computing the images of the other roots we see that $\sigma$ corresponds to the permutation $(12)(36)(45)$.

Complex conjugation $\rho$ will also be an automorphism of your field, and by plotting the roots on the complex plane we see that $\rho=(16)(25)(34)$.

As products of these we get the other non-trivial automorphisms as permutations of roots:
$$
\rho\sigma=(153)(264),\quad \sigma\rho=(135)(246),
\quad\sigma\rho\sigma=\rho\sigma\rho=(14)(23)(56).
$$
The generators $\sigma$ and $\rho$ satisfy the relations $\sigma^2=\rho^2=(\sigma\rho)^3=1$, so they generate a copy of $S_3$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the order of the subgroup of $\,S_6\,$ generated by $\,(1\,4)\,,\,(1\,2)\,,\,(1\,3\,2)\,$ is way larger than $\,6\,$ ...Either you made some mistake when calculating the order of the Galoi group (which you didn't since the extension you're talking about is simple with minimal polynomial of degree $\,6\,$), or else you didn't calculate correctly the cycles corresponding to the elements of the group.

**Added** Seeing the comment by Jyrki I realize your mistake appears, apparently, before all your computations: indeed $\,a^6\neq -3\,$ as it should! You'd in fact need $\,a:=\sqrt[6]{3}\,e^{\pi i/6}\,$

Answer (score 2):

Your $\tau$ isn't $(14)$; it's $(14)(23)(56)$. I'd check the other ones, too, if I were you.